# Classical mechanics kinetic energy string

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

A particle of mass m on a smooth horizontal table is attached to a string of length l passing through a small hole in the table and carries a particle of equal mass hanging vertically.

The position of the particle on the table is given in terms of its distance r from the hole and of the angle θ the string makes with some fixed line in the table.

The position of the other particle is given in terms of its vertical distance from the table.

Question:  Derive Lagrange's equation for the system in terms of the generalized coordinates r and and $\theta$.

I was able to deduce that the potential energy is $U=mgr$. But how do I construct the kinetic energy in terms of $r$ and $\theta$?

Comment: Arc length in polars: $v^2=\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\theta}^2$.

Comment: ^ that will give you the velocity you need for the rotating one, and after applying the no-stretch condition to the string you should be able to relate the velocity of the other mass to $\dot{r}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

We know

$$
p = \rho(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\Rightarrow \dot p = \dot\rho(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)+\rho(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)\dot\theta\Rightarrow \|\dot p\|^2=\dot \rho^2+\rho^2\dot\theta^2
$$

now falling vertically

$$
\cases{
T_1 = \frac 12 m_1 \dot\rho_1^2\\
U_1 = -\rho_1 m _1 g
}
$$

and on the table

$$
\cases{
T_2 = \frac 12m_2(\dot \rho_2^2+\rho_2^2\dot\theta^2)\\
U_2 = 0
}
$$

Note that

$$
\rho_1 + \rho_2 = \rho_0
$$